# Object declaration error

Tags: c++, matrix

I have a very strange issue when creating an object of the class  "CorrelatedNormalGenerator". Please see code below. The class Matrix is used by the class CorrelatedNormalGenerator. Thanks in advance for your help.

in Matrix.h

```
  #include <string>
  #include <vector>

   using namespace std;


   template <typename T, typename I>
   class Matrix
    {

      private:

        vector<vector<T> > M;
        I minRowIndex, maxRowIndex;
        I minColIndex, maxColIndex;
        I rowNumber, colNumber;



       public:

        Matrix();  // default constructor

        Matrix(const I& _rowNumber,   
                const I& _colNumber, 
                 const T& value = 0.0, 
                  const I&   _minRowIndex = 0, 
                    const I& _minColIndex = 0);

        Matrix<T,I>& operator = (const Matrix<T,I>& N);
    Matrix(const Matrix<T,I>& N); // copy constructor,
    virtual  ~Matrix(){};



        T& operator() (const I& row, const I& col);

        const T& operator() (const I& row, const I& col) const;


};

template<typename T, typename I>
Matrix<T,I> :: Matrix(const Matrix<T,I>& N) 
{
   M = N.M;
   rowNumber = N.GetRows();
   colNumber = N.GetCols();
   minRowIndex = N.minRowIndex;
   minColIndex = N.minColIndex;
   maxRowIndex = N.minRowIndex + N.rowNumber - 1;
   maxColIndex = N.minColIndex + N.colNumber - 1;
}



template<typename T, typename I>
Matrix<T,I> :: Matrix( const I& _rowNumber,
                   const I& _colNumber,
                   const T& value,
                   const I& _minRowIndex,
                   const I& _minColIndex)

{
   minRowIndex = _minRowIndex;
   minColIndex = _minColIndex;

   maxRowIndex = _minRowIndex + _rowNumber - 1;
   maxColIndex = _minColIndex + _colNumber - 1;

   rowNumber = _rowNumber;
   colNumber = _colNumber;

M.resize(rowNumber);

for (I i = minRowIndex ; i < rowNumber; i++)
    M[i].resize(colNumber, value);

}

template<typename T, typename I>
T& Matrix<T,I> :: operator() (const I& row, const I& col)
{
   return  M[row][col];
}

// Access the individual elements (const)

template<typename T, typename I>
const T& Matrix<T,I> :: operator() (const I& row, const I& col) const
{
    return  M[row][col];
}


template<typename T, typename I>
Matrix<T,I>& Matrix<T,I> :: operator = (const Matrix<T,I>& N) 
{ 
   rowNumber = N.GetRows();
   colNumber = N.GetCols();
   minRowIndex = N.minRowIndex;
   minColIndex = N.minColIndex;
   maxRowIndex = N.minRowIndex + N.rowNumber - 1;
   maxColIndex = N.minColIndex + N.colNumber - 1;

   M.resize(rowNumber);
   I i,j;

   for (i= minRowIndex; i <= maxRowIndex; i++)
   {
       M[i].resize(colNumber);
   }

   for (i= minRowIndex; i <= maxRowIndex; i++)
   {
        for (j = minColIndex; j <= maxColIndex; j++)
        {
            M[i][j] = N(i,j);
        }
   }

   return *this;
}
```

in CorrelatedNormalGenerator.h

```
#include "Matrix.h"
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;


template <typename T, typename I>   //  I = paramanter of matrix
class CorrelatedNormalGenerator 
{

  private:
         Matrix <T,I> SIGMA; // covariance matrix



  public:

      CorrelatedNormalGenerator(Matrix <T,I>& _SIGMA);


      vector <T> GetCorrVectorSingleAsset(const vector<T>& uncorrVector1, 
                                     const vector<T>&    uncorrVector2);

      vector <T> GetCorrVectorMultiAsset(const vector<T>& uncorrVector);  

      virtual ~CorrelatedNormalGenerator(){};

 };

template <typename T, typename I>
CorrelatedNormalGenerator<T,I> ::  CorrelatedNormalGenerator(Matrix <T,I>& _SIGMA)
{
     SIGMA =_SIGMA;
}



template <typename T, typename I>
vector <T>  CorrelatedNormalGenerator<T,I> :: GetCorrVectorMultiAsset(const vector<T>&    uncorrVector)
{
      Matrix<T,I> Chol = SIGMA.Cholesky();

      return Chol*uncorrVector;
}

template <typename T, typename I>
vector <T>  CorrelatedNormalGenerator<T,I> :: GetCorrVectorSingleAsset(const vector<T>&    uncorrVector1, const vector<T>& uncorrVector2)
 {
      vector<T> corrVector(uncorrVector1.size());

      for (unsigned i = 0; i < uncorrVector1.size(); i++)
          corrVector[i] = rho*uncorrVector1[i] + sqrt(1- rho*rho)*uncorrVector2[i];

      return corrVector;
 }
```

in MAIN.cpp

```
   #include "CorrelatedNormalGenerator.h"

   using namespace std;

   int main()
   {

    Matrix<double, int> P (3,3,0.0);

    P(0,0) = 1.0;
    P(1,1) = 1.0;
    P(2,2) = 1.0;
    P(1,2) = P(2,1) = 0.5;
    P(0,1) = P(1,0) = 0.6;
    P(0,2) = P(2,0) = 0.3;

    CorrelatedNormalGenerator<double, int> gen(P);  // ERROR: MAIN.cpp MAIN.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Matrix<double,int>::Matrix<double,int>(void)" (??0?$Matrix@NH@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall CorrelatedNormalGenerator<double,int>::CorrelatedNormalGenerator<double,int>(class Matrix<double,int> &)" (??0?$CorrelatedNormalGenerator@NH@@QAE@AAV?$Matrix@NH@@@Z) 

    return 0;
   }
```

Comment: it is telling you that you did not implement the Matrix default constructor, and I don't see it in the code you posted. Write the code for Matrix<T,I>::Matrix<T,I>().

Comment: Thanks now it works! Could you explain why in this case the default constructor was compulsory? How can I understand when I need it and when I don't? Thank you

Comment: because since you didnt instanciate the Matrix in initialization list of the constructor, it tries to call the default constructor(`Matrix<T, U>()`), which is not defined even tho it is declared. Make it private, or make it deleted to hint that it is not to be used if you have C++11 compatible compiler(`Matrix() = delete;`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is telling you that you did not implement the Matrix default constructor, and I don't see it in the code you posted. Add the code for

```
Matrix<T,I>::Matrix<T,I>()
```

It is needed because you define a matrix in CorrelatedNormalGenerator without initializing it in an initializer list using one of the other Matrix ctors, hence the need for default ctor :

```
private:
     Matrix <T,I> SIGMA; // covariance matrix
```

Comment: I'd like to add that `CorrelatedNormalGenerator` does fill in the `Matrix` instance by copying one over. Using the initializer list would avoid making a useless default-constructed one that is subsequently overwritten.